# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{x+\ln (1-x)}{x^2}}$ without derivatives

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If we know that $$\lim\limits_{x\to 1}{\frac{\ln x}{x-1}}=1$$ and $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{x+\ln (1-x)}{x^2}}=l\in\mathbb{R}$$ find the value of $l$ **without derivatives**.

I have only managed to find that: $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{\ln (1-x)}{x}}=-1$$ Any hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Change $x\to 0$ to $(-x)\to 0$ to get
   $$
   \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x+\ln(1+x)}{x^2}=l.
   $$
2. Add two limits
   $$
   2l=l+l=\lim_{x\to 0}\Bigl(\frac{x+\ln(1-x)}{x^2}+\frac{-x+\ln(1+x)}{x^2}\Bigr)=
   \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x^2}.
   $$
3. Change $x^2=t\to 0$ to get
   $$
   2l=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}=-1.
   $$
   Thus, $l=-\frac12$.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for sharing :).

Comment: Nice. How to guarantee that limits exist?

Comment: @JohnMa The question itself guaranteed...

Comment: @Asydot : This is really a general question.

Comment: @JohnMa As I understand it is given that the limit exists and is equal to $l$.

Comment: @A.G. Yes, I understand that. Your proof is very nice. I was asking how one would know $\ell$ exist.

Comment: From the hypothesis, $l\in\mathbb{R}$ so it exists. Great proof!!!

Comment: you can apply Hopital rule check this and see "show step by step":http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%2Bln%281-x%29%7D%7Bx%C2%B2%7D%2Cx%5Cto+0