# Calculate $\lim_{x \to 0} (\cot^3(x)·x·(\ln(1+3x)-3x))$

Tags: calculus, limits

I do not seem to be be able to calculate this limit. I tired many things using l'Hospital but it gets messier. A useful limit is $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ as $x\to0$. But still it still does not give the desired result. Any hints? Suggestions?
$$\lim_{x \to 0} (\cot^3(x)·x·(\ln(1+3x)-3x))$$

Comment: The limit seems to be $\;-\cfrac92\;$ , but: can you use L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: @DonAntonio I can use any method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$L = \lim_{x \to 0} {x\cot^3(x)(\ln(1+3x)-3x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} {\dfrac{\ln(1+3x)-3x}{x^2}} = 9\lim_{x \to 0} {\dfrac{\ln(1+3x)-3x}{(3x)^2}}$$

Let $y = 3x$

$$\lim_{y \to 0} {\dfrac{\ln(1+y)-y}{y^2}} = \dfrac{-1}2$$

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936642/450905). So $L = \dfrac{-9}{2}$

Comment: where does $x^2$ come from?

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan Multiply and divide by $x^2$.

Comment: i dont see what happens with $cot^3x$

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan $\lim_{x \to 0}\cos^3 x \left(\dfrac{x}{\sin x}\right)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\cot^3(x)\cdot x\cdot (\ln(1+3x)-3x)=(x^3\cot^3(x))\cdot \frac{\ln(1+3x)-3x}{x^2}=\\=(x^3\cot^3(x))\cdot \frac{3x-\frac{9x^2}{2}+o(x^2)-3x}{x^2}=(x^3\cot^3(x))\cdot \left(-\frac{9}{2}+o(1)\right)\to1\cdot\left(-\frac{9}{2}\right)=-\frac{9}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {(\cos^3 x)(x)(\ln (1+3x) - 3x)}{\sin^3 x}$

You can do a taylor expansion...

$\frac { (1)(x)(+3x - \frac {(3x)^2}{2} - 3x)}{x^3}\\
-\frac {9}{2}$

Comment: how about not using  taylor expansion

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+3x)-3x}{\sin^2x}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac3{1+3x}-3}{\sin2x}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac9{(1+3x)^2}}{2\cos2x}=-\frac92$$

and then

$$\lim_{x\to0}\;\cot^3x\cdot x\cdot\left(\log(1+3x)-3x\right)=\lim_{x\to0}\,\cos^3x\cdot\frac x{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\log(1+3x)-3x}{\sin^2x}=1\cdot1\cdot\left(-\frac92\right)=-\frac92$$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hopital will work if you do a little housework beforehand. The expression equals

$$ \cos^3 x\cdot\frac{x^3}{\sin^3 x}\cdot\frac{x(\ln (1+3x) - 3x)}{x^3}.$$

The first two fractions $\to 1,$ so we need only study the last fraction. This equals

$$\frac{\ln (1+3x) - 3x}{x^2}.$$

Now it's fairly easy to use L'Hopital.

Answer (score -1):

Without l'Hopital, Taylor expansions or calculus:

$$\begin{aligned}
L&=\frac{x\left(\ln(1+3x)-3x\right)}{\tan^3(x)}
\\
u&=3x
\\
L&=9\left(\frac{x}{\tan x}\right)^3\frac{\ln(1+u)-u}{u^2}
\\
\lim L&=9\cdot1^3\cdot-\frac12\quad
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Using the standard limits of $\lim\frac{x}{\tan x}$ and [$\lim\frac{\ln(1+u)-u}{u^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443421/find-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracx-ln-1-xx2-without-derivatives.).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their downvote?